# Automatically create another entry after user posts a data Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

when user submits a pet, the petid would be stored in the table 'likes' with the default value in numOflikes 0. I am not sure how to approach this other than doing 2 post requests which seems tedious

What I tried:

submitting a pet post request and then grabbing id and doing another post request for 'likes'

Model

```
class pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)



class likes(models.Model):
    petId = models.ForeignKey(
        "pet", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    numOflikes = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Serializer

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = pet
        fields = '__all__'

class LikesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = likes
        fields = '__all__'
```

expected
pet

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "dog",
    },
```

likes

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "petid": 1
         "numOflikes": 0
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `create()` method of `PetSerializer`.

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = pet
        fields = '__all__'


    def create(self, validated_data):
        pet_obj = pet.objects.create(name=validated_data['name'])
        likes.objects.create(petId=pet_obj)
        return pet_obj
```

Comment: lets say i have more fields , would i need to put them all in create?

Comment: then you can do something `like pet_obj.objects.create(**validated_data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Model;

```py
class likes(models.Model):
    petId = models.ForeignKey(
        "pet", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    numOflikes = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

class pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created = False
        if self.id is None:
            created = True

        super(pet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created:
            likes.objects.create(petId=self.id)

    def get_like_count(self):
        return likes.objects.get(petId=self.id).numOflikes
```

Serializer;

```py
from .models import likes
from rest_framework import serializers

class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    numOflikes = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='get_like_count'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = pet
        fields = '__all__'
```